# Optional statement to check when folder exists or not

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

This line gets the directory name

```
 let directory = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: image).deletingPathExtension?.lastPathComponent  //
```

Now I'm interested to check if entire path exists. However, if I attempt this line of code:

```
     if let imageDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent(directory!, isDirectory: true)
```

I get the error, message "initializer for conditoinal binding must have OPtional type, not URL"

I've tried `directory?` as well.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got the error cause if you use the construction

> if let something = ...

you have to try to unwrap optional properties. But in your example you unwrap nothing cause your property is

> first!

My solution

```
if let directory = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: image).deletingPathExtension?.lastPathComponent,
   let imageDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent(directory, isDirectory: true) {

}
```

EDIT1:

Using URL Instead NSURL:

```
let directory = URL(fileURLWithPath: image).deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent
if let imageDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first?.appendingPathComponent(directory, isDirectory: true) {}
```

Comment: Do not use NSURL in Swift.

Comment: @rmaddy What should I use instead? Thank you.